# Alternative to regexp $1 for replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to modify a substring with .replace() in javascript.

Basically I want to put arbitrary text before and after the match.

```
var pattern = new RegExp("<div"+"(.*?)>", "g");

var text = "<div><div class='someClass'>"

text = text.replace(pattern, "<pre>"+"<div>"+ "$1" + ">" +"</pre>")
```

The code above changes text to:

```
"<pre><div>></pre><pre><div> class='someClass'></pre>"
```

Besides the extra ">>" this is correct, but it is ugly in the replace function.

How can I change my regex so I

1. Dont have to use $1 because it is not fully supported [according to this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n)
2. How can I change replace to something simpler like

   ```
   text = text.replace(pattern, "<pre>"+ "THING_THAT_MATCHED" +"</pre>")
   ```

Comment: `$1` in the replacement pattern is and will be supported.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Sure, [MDN String#replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). You mistake `RegExp` properties like `RegExp.$1` and backreferences inside a replacement pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("<div"+"(.*?)>", "g");

var text = "<div><div class='someClass'>"

text = text.replace(pattern, function(match, first_match) {
    return "<pre>"+"<div>"+ first_match + ">" +"</pre>"
})
```

---

Also note that you code make your original code much neater, like so:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("<div"+"(.*?)>", "g");

var text = "<div><div class='someClass'>"

text = text.replace(pattern, "<pre><div>$1></pre>")
```